# TextInputLayout isn't looking as it should

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, material-design, android-textinputlayout

I need to use an OutlinedBox TextInputLayout but when I try to do that in my app it doesn't work, because the line under the text remains.
Expected result:

[image]

Result:

[image]

This is the code:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/editTextEmail"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="305dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:hint="E-mail"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.07999998">


        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:layout_height="60dp" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

I am using Material Dependency 1.1.0. I already tried to remove the theme line (but of course my app crashed because my main theme is AppCompat), I tested also in a blank project but nothing different happens.
What can I do? Thanks for your help

EDIT:

I partially solved using the Material Dependency at 1.0.0 but why it doesn't work with 1.1?

Comment: I would start removing ```android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar"```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, I changed another time the main theme of my app to Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar but the app still crashed.

Comment: android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge"

Comment: thanks for your comment, @FahadAlotaibi. Unfortunately, even this change has solved my problem.

Comment: watch this video i strongly recommend it for everyone whats to know about material theme https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=92DL3-IQ_K0&list=PL4ebO4PmeAi6jtfp4QcZCEIQ3mBSgq-ck&index=17&t=0s

Comment: Thanks! that's really useful

Comment: I was having the same issue and changing my app theme in styles.xml to `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">` did the trick for me. Hope this works for you as well.

Comment: You **can't use** an AppCompat with the 1.1.0. Just migrate your app theme.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the tip. After that change I was still stucked, but then I discovered that the previous app dev was overwriting every activity theme in the manifest